# How to politely notify someone that they are not using proper car safety (possibly against the law)?

Tags: strangers, cars, safety

The title feel awkward, so if anyone can improve it, that would be great. Here's what I mean:

Sometimes you walk along the street and see someone in a car without a seat belt. Let's assume it's summer, the window is open, they're sitting at a red light or something and you *could* talk to them, even if just for a moment.

Or a bigger one - people who have children in their car without any restraints at all. No child seat, no seat belt, nothing. Sometimes you also see an infant in the lap of an adult. These can be seen in parking lots or when parents drop their children off at daycare - also times when it's possible to approach them.

These are all against the law, and if there was even a small accident, the consequences are potentially devastating.

Sometimes there are also smaller problems - an obviously wrongly installed child seat; a child seat that does not fit the child; etc.

It kinda feels like I should do something, speak out... but on the other hand, it's none of my business. Telling them flat out will most likely result in a hostile reaction. On occasion it looks more like somebody simply didn't know what they were doing (so they could even be receptive to corrections), but when you see someone without a seat belt, then that's obviously a choice and not a lack of knowledge. And if there's a similarly unsecured child next to them, who really doesn't know any better and was just doing what mom told them...

What should one do in such a situation? Can such people be spoken to in a manner that makes them reconsider their behavior? Or should they just be let alone and the natural selection allowed to take its course?

Comment: Does your country have a non-emergency police telephone line? That's where I've reported blatant (but not immediately) life-threatening disregards for safety like those you have described.

Comment: Currently you're asking "What to do" which is off-topic here, see the [help centre](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on what type of questions are on topic. Once you decide on a course of action and would like help on how to go about it, then we could help you.

Comment: @VioletFlare - Well... your links says: `using or understanding interpersonal interactions to resolve specific problems or prevent problems from occurring with a specific goal in mind. This includes interactions with family, friends, work/school associates, acquaintances or strangers (or anyone else).` I think this falls under that umbrella. I'm trying to prevent a problem from occurring, and I'm wondering how to do it - even though I'm not sure it CAN be done.

Comment: Any way you cut it, approaching strangers and attempting to change their choices is rude, even if it is against the law. Their choices are their own, except in extreme cases such as blatant child endangerment. In any case, there are solutions and ways you can help, but unfortunately none of them involve interpersonal skills nor confrontation, therefore I'm voting to close.

Comment: @Clay07g I could have posed my example better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know how you feel, but there isn't much you could say to strangers face to face. You could though

- volunteer in organisations for safe driving awareness (delivering information sheets, organising events etc.)
- share information about safe driving on social media
- share unfortunate accidents on social media or with friends and family when there is a related conversation (this may be considered harsh, but I think it resembles the photos on cigarette packets - sometimes you have to shock in order to influence someone).

Some people just don't know better. Informing them in a in-depth way can make them think a little more - but you certainly cannot do that in an instance, while someone is waiting in a road light. Some people might think you are a beggar or you are trying to harass them in some way and close the window or ignore you whatsoever. They are more likely to pay attention to stuff they CHOSE to read/listen - and unfortunately people tend to pay attention to unfortunate events 'advertised' on social media as '***You won't believe*** what happened to this 5 yo boy when his father crushed on a tree!!!!!'.